# login to multiples URLs with user/password and export information to an excel

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning, I need to automatize a daily control that we must do. In every URL we have information about the servers status in tabs.

I tried did that with excel Data > From Web, but when I share the file with my partners they aren't logged into the urls, so the automate itn't working fine. We need to open, for example an excel, refresh and get the information about the server status. I tried with multiples examples shared in this web, but I had no success.

There are 17 urls, some with the same user and password.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If it's using HTTP authentication, you can try adding `username:password@` between the URI scheme and the domain name.

For example:

```
https://username:password@yourdomain.com/
```

From http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt:

```
   Those schemes which refer to internet protocols mostly have a
   common syntax for the rest of the object name. This starts with a
   double slash "//" to indicate its presence, and continues until the
   following slash "/".  Within that section are   


      An optional user name, 
                              if required (as it is with a few FTP
                             servers). The password, is present, follows
                             the user name, separated from it by a colon;
                             the user name and optional password are
                             followed by a commercial at sign "@".  The
                             user of user name and passwords which are
                             public is discouraged.
```

Note that you need to [% encode](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#userinfo-encode-set) the username & password if they contain special characters.